# Can Files Be Compressed Without Changing Extension?

Tags: conversion, compression, file-extension

It's common for web servers to pre-compress their files with brotli or gzip. And they do so without changing the extensions of the files. Is their a way to do this in a typical desktop environment (ex. Windows 10)?

Ex. Can I compress example.txt with deflate without it becoming example.gz or example.zip, but instead remaining example.txt? If not, why can this be done on web servers but not on desktops?

Comment: I also have the same question. Thanks for asking

Comment: The web server sends a header before sending the data, so the recipient knows it will be receiving compressed data. Thus the file extension plays no part in it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I really doubt that the web is the focus of this question. To assume otherwise like you have seems simply strange, not least because such information isn't particularly actionable outside that specific context.

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart That's why it's a comment. The OP might not have been aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows NTFS has a built in transparent file compression feature that works in the way you are imagining.

Essentially the data is compressed before being sent to disk and transparently decompressed while being read by an application.

You can read more at [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/133264/how-to-use-ntfs-compression-and-when-you-might-want-to/) and you can access the feature by

1. right-clicking a file or folder,
2. go to the "Properties" item at the bottom
3. click the "Advanced" button in the window that pops up
4. Check the "compress contents to save disk space" box and then click "OK"
5. Click "Apply" or "OK" in the properties window

Windows will then compress your file or files.

Your files will be compressed (on disk) but will appear as if they are not compressed to any application using them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I'm aware of this. I'm interested in specifically deflate, deflate64, or brotli compression without an extension.

Comment: @abcjme, the compression *method* doesn't matter - merely, it must be performed by the filesystem or specifically supported by the file *type* to be “transparent”, unfortunately. See https://superuser.com/a/1819327/904401

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this compression must either:

- Be supported by the file type and the interpreting software:

  This has the benefit of not being filesystem-dependent, meaning that the compression remains regardless of whatever filesystem is used, and cannot be removed during transferral.

  However, this has the disadvantage of being manually applied to each file, rather than automatically applied by the filesystem, and can provide some serious slowness when utilized in tandem with filesystem compression methods.
- Be supported by the filesystem:

  This has the benefit of not requiring that the interpreting software possess decodement abilities for the specific compression method utilized.

  However, I do not know of any filesystem which supports a diverse enough, and file-specific, range of compression methods to provide useful compression for each disparate file type which supports it. Consequently, this is best utilized as a comprehensive backuip solution rather than the go-to, especially for large files.

For instance, although (per https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Compression.html) BTRFS supports

1. LZO,
2. ZLIB, and
3. ZSTD,

none of these compression methods are useful for `.TIFF` files. Rather, in my experience, *Deflate* is best utilized. This means that I shouldn't rely upon the filesystem whatsoever.